# Find hand contours only. Python. OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

[I have foreground mask, like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29CH4.png)

[If I use findContours method I receive this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJhaA.png)

I want to find only main contours on hand without trash. How can I do it?

```
thresh = 100
    # get threshold image
    ret, thresh_img = cv.threshold(fgMask, thresh, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
    # find contours
    contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh_img, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # create an empty image for contours
    img_contours = np.zeros(img.shape)
    # draw the contours on the empty image
    cv.drawContours(img_contours, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

    cv.imwrite("img.png", fgMask)
    cv.imwrite("img1.png", img_contours)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try blurring image before threshold to reduce the noise.
**However**, your foreground mask is quite bad actually for this purpose. Since I cannot see what you have done before, it is generally better to use HSV color space if you want to achieve human skin. [Because](https://nalinc.github.io/blog/2018/skin-detection-python-opencv/)

> The color of human skin is created by a combination of blood (red) and
> melanin (yellow, brown). Skin colors lie between these two extreme
> hues and are somewhat saturated.
> HSV: (Hue-Saturation-Value) defined in a way that is similar to how
> humans perceive color.

```
img_path = "hand.jpg"
img = cv.imread(img_path)

# define the upper and lower boundaries of the HSV pixel intensities 
# to be considered 'skin'
hsvim = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 48, 80], dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array([20, 255, 255], dtype="uint8")
skinMask= cv.inRange(hsvim, lower, upper)

# blur the mask to help remove noise
skinMask= cv.blur(skinMask, (2, 2))

# get threshold image
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(skinMask, 100, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
cv.imshow("thresh", thresh)

# draw the contours on the empty image
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = max(contours, key=lambda x: cv.contourArea(x))
cv.drawContours(img, [contours], -1, (255, 255, 0), 2)
cv.imshow("contours", img)

cv.waitKey()
```

should resulted better like[image]

[Code Reference](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/hand-detection-and-finger-counting-using-opencv-python-5b594704eb08)